# What is the difference between XML and XAML in Dot Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I have started Visual programming in .net frame work, i have encountered a question during my first lesson.

Comment: Every Xaml is an Xml, however not every Xml is an Xaml.

Comment: What research have you done into the subject? We prefer people to make a little bit of effort before asking a question.

Comment: Xaml is just an Xml used by VS to specify the layout of an aplication. Xml itself is far more general and could be used by any app, not just VS.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. There are a lot of questions that have very long and exhaustive answers, this could easily be one of them. Also it has plenty of views, we have shifted a lot of traffic to other platforms that manage to cover this question and it's a shame.

Answer (score 4):

While `XAML` uses the standards defined in `XML` it has way more abilities and is specialized to be used for GUI-Design comparable to `HTML`.
So to sum things up `XML` is a Format Structure and `XAML` is a design language for interfaces based on XML-Standards